# how to implement infinite scroll (paging) with remote data with angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, scroll, paging, infinite, jquery-select2

I want to achieve the same effect of select2 in angularjs:

[enter link description here](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#data-ajax)

It seems somebody has already raised a similiar issue, but has not been adressed by the angular-ui-select team. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use ngInfiniteScroll:
https://sroze.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/

Comment: it seems ngInfiniteScroll is for the scrolling of the whole browser page, not only the drop down box.